# How can I re-request permission for camera

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am using these codes

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {CAMERA, RECORD_AUDIO ,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

    if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
```

and

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

My app requires to move to next activity only if camera, write storage and record audio permissions are provided. How can I re-request if any of the request is denied.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
        int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
        if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] permission_list = new String[1];
            permission_list[0] = permission;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
        }
```

and use `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method to handle permission result that user grant the permission or not

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```